# How to display list from middle value of arraylist

Tags: android

I have to do like below.

1. get array from server (Date(TextView), Hours(Edittext -> add,delete,update))
2. Display 11 item in list for first screen - ex current date in middle and 5 previous date and 5 future date.
3. Next and Previous button - next button display 11 future date comes from array, and same previous display 11 dates per screen like pagination.

i can able to display data and when press next button it show next 11 items // but i want to set list from current date. 
and then user press next button it will show next 11 item end of the array. 
and user press previous button it will show previous date from current by 11 item end of the list.

also automatic changing the value of edittext when i will going to edit or delete

below is my code

> ```
> int NUM_ITEMS_JUMP= 0;
> int NUM_ITEMS_PAGE = 11;
> int licount = 0;
> private void loadList(int number) {
>     moByDayArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
>     for (int i = -50; i < 0; i++) {
>         moByDayArrayList.add(new ByDay(Common.getCalculatedDates(Common.getCurrentDate(), i), "3"));
>     }
>     //Previous 60 Days
>     for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
>         //moByDayArrayList.add(new ByDay(Common.getCalculatedDate(i)));
>         moByDayArrayList.add(new ByDay(Common.getCalculatedDates(Common.getCurrentDate(), i), "5"));
>     }
>     System.out.println("moByDayArrayList.size() " + moByDayArrayList.size());
>     ArrayList<ByDay> sort = new ArrayList<ByDay>();
>     for (int i = number; i < (number) + NUM_ITEMS_PAGE; i++) {
>         if (i < moByDayArrayList.size()) {
>             sort.add(moByDayArrayList.get(i));
>             System.out.println("sort.size() sort  " + sort.size());
>         } else {
>             System.out.println("No more");
>             if (licount == 1) {
>                 Common.makeAlert(getActivity(), "No more data available", true);
>             } else {
>                 licount++;
>             }
>             break;
>         }
>     }
>     NUM_ITEMS_JUMP+= 11;
>     byDayListAdapter = new ByDayListAdapter(getActivity(), sort);
>     moLvByDay.setAdapter(byDayListAdapter);
>    //moLvByDay.setSelection(moByDayArrayList.indexOf(moByDayArrayList.get(40).getStartDate()));  // Not Working
>  }
> ```

onCreate

```
 loadList(0);
```

Next Button Click

```
 loadList(NUM_ITEMS_JUMP);
```

Adapter

> ```
> public class ByDayListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ByDay> {
> Context context;
> List<ByDay> maByDay;
> @Override
> public int getCount() {
>     return maByDay.size();
> }
> public ByDayListAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId) {
>     super(context, resource, textViewResourceId);
> }
> public ByDayListAdapter(Context context, List<ByDay> faByDay) {
>     super(context, 0, faByDay);
>     this.context = context;
>     this.maByDay = faByDay;
> }
> @Override
> public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
>     // Get the data item for this position
>     ByDay loByDay = getItem(position);
>     // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
>     if (convertView == null) {
>         convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listitem_byday, parent, false);
>     }
>     // Lookup view for data population
>     EditText etName = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etByDayTime);
>     TextView tvHome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvByDayDate);
>     if (Common.getCurrentDate().equalsIgnoreCase(loByDay.getStartDate())) {
>         System.out.println("from day --  lsStartDate....  " + loByDay.getStartDate() + "\nCommon.getCurrentDate().......  " + Common.getCurrentDate());
>         tvHome.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD));
>         tvHome.setTextColor(ActivityCompat.getColor(context, R.color.black_light));
>     } else {
>         tvHome.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.NORMAL));
>         tvHome.setTextColor(ActivityCompat.getColor(context, R.color.gray));
>     }
>     tvHome.setText(loByDay.getStartDate());
>     etName.setText(loByDay.getHours());
>     etName.addTextChangedListener(new EditTextWatcher(loByDay));
>     // Return the completed view to render on screen
>     return convertView;
> }
> public class EditTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
>     private ByDay byDay;
>     public EditTextWatcher(ByDay byDay) {
>         this.byDay = byDay;
>     }
>     @Override
>     public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
>         byDay.setHours(s.toString());
>     }
>     @Override
>     public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
>                                   int arg3) {
>     }
>     @Override
>     public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
>     }
> }
> }
> ```

Screen Shot

[image]

How to get this approach?? is there any other way? or can do it by listview? Please help me for this.